# How to add custom color toolbar button in tinymce editor

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-6

I am using tinymce editor version 6 in my application. Now, I have requirement to add 1 more color picker button same as like forecolor/backcolor button in editor to do some more thing. On this custom color button, I want to change editor background color.

As per tinymce documentation, I can add simple button, split button, toggle button and grouped button but I can't find anything to add color button.

Can someone please help me how can I add custom color button in tinymce editor? I am using tinymce version 6.

Thanks in advance.